# SQL Northwind Practice

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

I have a practice question:

> Show for each order item – the customer name and order id, product name, ordered quantity, product price and total price (Ordered quantity * product price) and gap between ordered date and shipped date (the gap in days). Order by order id.

**Northwind** of course.

My query was:

```
SELECT 
    C.ContactName, O.OrderID, P.ProductName, 
    OD.Quantity, OD.UnitPrice, 
    OD.Quantity * OD.UnitPrice as [Total Price]
FROM 
    Orders O, Customers C, Products P, [Order Details] OD
WHERE 
    C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
    AND O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
    AND OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
ORDER BY 
    O.OrderID;
```

The thing I do not get is: What is "gap between date and shipped date". I don't get it.

Thanks.

Comment: Learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: [Avoid using the old-style `JOIN` syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: Gap between order date and shipped date just means "how many days between the order date and the shipped date". If the order date is 04/21/2016 and the shipped date is 04/24/2016, the gap is 3 days.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Isn't the advice to never use commas in the `FROM` clause over the top and misleading? Obviously, we can influence some QO decisions but the query optimizer is in general still able to select an efficient join algorithm so we can write queries as we are comfortable expressing... isn't that the beauty of a declarative language at the end of the day?

Answer (score 3):

Pertinent to your question, the gap between ordered date and shipped date refers to the calculated value of:

```
DATEDIFF(day, date_ordered, date_shipped) AS GapDays
```

using SQL `DATEDIFF`() function, where `date_ordered` and `date_shipped` corresponds to the field names in your Table (you may need to rename them as per the actual fields; also, correct the JOIN syntax as explained here; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx).

Hope this may help.